# how to set only required properties to angular select object using ng-option?

Tags: angularjs

I have object array which contains objects along with many properties. I am binding it to the select tag using angular ng-options

[Demolink](http://plnkr.co/edit/BXEk41fwzLGO6zOHaPeq?p=preview)

Once user selects the value in the combobox, controller property is updated(here it is $scope.selectedIem={"selected":""}). But this selected propriety contains all the property list name.

eg:

```
                  {"description":"Bank",
                     "shortDescription":"dd",
                     "value":"xx",
                      "enable":null,
                      "name":"jhon"

                  },
```

But I want only

```
                  {
                     "shortDescription":"dd",
                     "value":"xx",

                  },
```

Kindly, help me how can pass only required properties to "select object" by using ng-options

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `ng-change`, when your are selecting an object you just need to call a function using `ng-change` and in that function you need to deleted the unwanted attributes of the selectedItem in `ng-model`

Here is the working plunker

http://embed.plnkr.co/IX1HFV9o3rOb0c8AcjmP/preview

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks, can it be done using ng-option, because for label value we call function, just like that, can I call function for object value